# jquery parent() doesn't work after ajax calls

Tags: jquery

Since the class is added dynamically, we use event handler for ajax loaded content such as :

```
$('.menu').click(function(){
.....
})
```

To

```
$(document).on('click','.menu',function(){
.....
})
```

Same here, following function is working in same page, but while using in after ajax loaded, it isn't working. How can I use event handler for this ?

```
$('.submenu').parent().each(function(){
    if ($(this).children("ul").length) {
        $(this).find('.submenu').html('+');
    }
})
```

Comment: Hard to say with so few code... But try `$(document).on('click', 'input[name^="nav"]', function() {}` where `^=` means "begins with".

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette, my question is how to bind `$('.submenu').parent().each(function(){`, not another one ( `$(document).on('click', 'input[name="nav[]"]', function() {}`) .. it is just reference, it is working.

Comment: Ok. Then show the HTML markup. How can I know what is the parent of `.submenu` and what is dynamically created in there?

Comment: $('.submenu').parent() should only match one element. So using `each()` iterator on what that returns is not needed. Aside from that what does `console.log(this)` inside your closure output? You should use some deductive reasoning when debugging. Find out what your selectors actually are returning. Then you can find out what methods and properties are available. `console.log`

Comment: You may want `$('.submenu').each(function(){ $(this).parent() ... });`

Answer (score 2):

You want a way to have something like that...

```
$(document).on('click', [ ---$('.submenu').parent()---] ,function(){

  // ...

});
```

*Could you simply give a class to those parents?

```
$(document).on('click', ".submenu" ,function(){

  $(this).parent()... 

});
```

The second selector passed to `.on()` will be looked up at the moment the callback executes. Then, you can find a parent of `$(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue with `$('.submenu').parent().each(function( ... ));` This bit of code will only ever make one iteration because the `parent()` method called on a selector will only traverse and select one parent element.

If you would like to select each `.submenu` to iterate over, the proper way to do that would be `$('.submenu').each(function(){ ... }));` then inside your closure do the code you want.

Since you didn't provide any HTML to speculate on I can only assume your structure is similar to:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class='menu'>
            <div class="submenu'>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            <div class="submenu">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="submenu">
                <!-- 
                    no unordered list here to match
                    this submenu is ignored
                -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class='menu'>
            <div class="submenu'>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            <div class="submenu">
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='menu'>
            <div class="submenu'>
                <ul>
                    <li></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

(If it is the latter then maybe calling the `parents()` method with your existing code will yield the result you want)

If it is the former then you probably want to match each `.submenu` then check if there is an unordered list as a child. If there is then add a '+' to it?

As an aside the `html()` method in jQuery is similar to `innerHTML` property for vanilla javascript. So `html('+')` would replace the contents with '+'.

If this is what you intend then your javascript would look like:

```
$('.submenu').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).has('ul') ) {
        $(this).html('+');
    }
});
```

Which is odd but I don't know what your end result is. Something that seems like it might make sense is to add '+' button if there is an unordered list and you'd like to add a list item:

```
$('.submenu').each(function(){
    if ( $(this).has('ul') ) {
        $(this).find('ul').append('+');
    }
});
```